# Using MAILTO in cronjob?

Tags: cron

Scenario 1:

```
     MAILTO=xyz@example.com
10 12 * * * /usr/local/bin/curator --dry-run --config /home/itadmin/.curator/curator.yml /home/itadmin/.curator/snapshotdaily.yml >> /home/itadmin/.curator/logs.txt 2>&1
```

By this all the STDOUT and STDERR are going to logs.txt.

Scenario 2 :

If i am using like this :

```
 10 12 * * * /usr/local/bin/curator --config /home/itadmin/.curator/curator.yml /home/itadmin/.curator/snapshotdaily.yml
```

I am getting mail but not getting stored in logs.txt

What i want is the combination of both 1 and 2: I want my every day logs appeneded to be in logs.txt file for history purpose and also want daily logs to be sent in mail .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `tee`:

```
10 12 * * * /usr/local/bin/curator --dry-run --config /home/itadmin/.curator/curator.yml /home/itadmin/.curator/snapshotdaily.yml 2>&1 | /usr/bin/tee -a /home/itadmin/.curator/logs.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Can you pls explain ` | /usr/bin/tee -a /home/itadmin/.curator/logs.txt` ? What does `/usr/bin/tee` path mean?

Comment: tee is a program that reads stdout and writes its content into specified location. -a stands for append, which means that logs.txt will not be overwritten.

Comment: Thanks.Whether the path is correct `/usr/bin/tee` or i have to keep `/usr/local/bin/tee`?

Comment: It depends on your environment. Try using `which tee` to retrieve correct path.