# How can i keep the give the subject of the email using postfix in crontab?

Tags: postfix, cron

Using MAILTO where can i give the subject of the email without using `echo Test | mail -s Test xyz@example.com` because if i use like this for sender to a one user it is okay if i want to add multiple user mails then for every script i have to add the mail id's which will be not good when comapare to MAILTO command.

Right now i have the script to send the mail to a user and send the STDOUT AND STDERR to logs.txt.

```
MAILTO="xyz@example.com,abc@example.com,rer@example.com"

25 07 * * * /usr/local/bin/curator --dry-run --config /home/itadmin/.curator/curator.yml /home/itadmin/.curator/snapshot.yml 2>&1 | /usr/bin/tee -a /home/itadmin/.curator/logs.txt
```

What i want is that in the MAILTO command is it possible to subject to all the users listed in that command like this `MAILTO="xyz@example.com,abc@example.com,rer@example.com?subject=Mail Tested"`

Thanks

Comment: You have asked a [number](https://serverfault.com/q/849033/37681)  of cron related [questions](https://serverfault.com/q/849282/37681) now and I just want to point out that Cron is only a simple scheduler. If you need more advanced functionality than just *run a specific command at a specific time* usually it is better to instead encode that logic in a script and just let cron call that script. Then you can do useful stuff like for instance catching the exit code of a command and send different messages based on succes or failure, send log files as attachments instead of body text etc.

Answer (score 1):

`MAILTO` in [crontab](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) is not a command but an *environment variable*.

For example, in Cron by Paul Vixie, `mailto` variable is set to `NULL` if it's empty and to username, if not present. Then, the `From:`, `To:` and `Subject:` are hard-coded to the program in `do_command.c`:

```
358     /* if we are supposed to be mailing, MAILTO will
359      * be non-NULL.  only in this case should we set
360      * up the mail command and subjects and stuff...
361      */
362
363     if (mailto) {

375         fprintf(mail, "From: root (Cron Daemon)\n");
376         fprintf(mail, "To: %s\n", mailto);
377         fprintf(mail, "Subject: Cron <%s@%s> %s\n",
378             usernm, first_word(hostname, "."),
379             e->cmd);
```

Therefore, you can't use `MAILTO` for changing the Subject. Instead, you could pipe the output to an external command sending mail or use an intermediate file and send its contents.